# iphone sdk subview/superview orientation problem

Tags: iphone, sdk, rotation, orientation, flip

i have a iphone sdk orientation issue...

i push a "holding" view controller onto the navigationController. The holdingViewController uses viewDidLoad to show the navigationController navbar and add a flip button to it and a selector for the flipbutton. it then adds a subview using UIViewAnimationTransitionNone showing a UIView containing a TableView. When the flip button is clicked the holding view controller removes the loaded subview and replaces with the another subview, also containing a view with a tableview, and transforms using the flip animation. The problem comes when flipping and changing orientations. although both flipping and rotating appear to work at first if i flip while in landscape mode, the flipped view is sort of "cropped" to portrait width, although actually displayed in landscape, rotation then doesnt fix it, u have to flip back, rotate back to portrait, then flip back again. It looks like the holdingview is not registering the change in orientation, but i know it is as i've implemented

```
[[UIDevice currentDevice] beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(orientationChanged:) name:UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification object:nil];
```

on all 3 view controllers and i can see orientationChanged function being called for each.

All three viewcontrollers are setting autoresizing in viewDidLoad

```
self.view.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
```

and i've also implemented

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation
{
 return YES;
}
```

does anybody have any ideas whats going on, or more importantly, what i can do to fix it?

many thanks

Comment: have you found a solution yet? i am facing a similar problem

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem with adding a subview. The subview was being cropped while in landscape orientation. I had to set the frame of the subview before adding it so that the subview would fill correctly.

Here is the code that fixed my issue: `[subcontroller.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.bounds.size.width, self.view.bounds.size.height)];`

Comment: This is the correct answer! I have a project that adds a view created in landscape orientation in IB as a subview of another landscape-only view. It kept coming up 'cropped,' but in the correct orientation. In fact, all of the buttons and labels were in the correct position, just the view background was 'cropped.' Re-defining the subview frame before adding it was the solution (and believe me, I tried everything!)